# Error BP5005: This loop invariant might not be maintained by the loop

Tags: dafny

I am new to Dafny. I don´t understand why I get this message with the `x == Sum(i);` I am starting to loos my mind. And also why does it compile when `if n==0 then 0 else n + Sum(n-1)` is turned into `if n==0 then 0 else n-1 + Sum(n-1)`

```
function Sum(n: nat): nat
{ 
    if n==0 then 0 else n + Sum(n-1)
}

method ComputeSum(n: nat) returns (x: nat) 
  ensures x == Sum(n);
{
  x := 0;
  var y := 0;
  var i : nat := 0;
    while i < n
      invariant 0 <= i <= n && x == Sum(i);
    {
      x,y := y,x + y ;
      i := i + 1;

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `x` and `y` to 0 but never increase them, so the addition remains 0. Dafny, correctly, proves that your program is not satisfying the specification. I'd suggest you step through your program for a small `n` to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question: if you change `if n==0 then 0 else n + Sum(n-1)` into `if n==0 then 0 else n-1 + Sum(n-1)`, the value of Sum(n) is 0 for every n. And that complies with ComputeSum, which returns 0 for all inputs n.